# How to retrieve specific data from XML in Oracle table

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, extract, extract-value

I have an oracle table which has a column that stores XML. The XML has the following syntax:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MessageData>
  <TextblockParameters>
    <TextblockParameter>
      <tagName>BUSINESSPROCESSID</tagName>
      <value>RETAIL</value>
    </TextblockParameter>
    <TextblockParameter>
      <tagName>SEGMENT</tagName>
      <value>RESIDENTIAL</value>
    </TextblockParameter>
    <TextblockParameter>
      <tagName>TRANSACTIONTYPE</tagName>
      <value>PURCHASE</value>
    </TextblockParameter>
    <TextblockParameter>
      <tagName>LANGUAGE</tagName>
      <value>EST</value>
    </TextblockParameter>
  </TextblockParameters>
</MessageData>
```

Now i need to get info from `<value></Value>`, from all 4 places. Please help with this issue, dont know if **Extractvalue** is best solution

Answer (score 4):

You can use `XMLTABLE` function for this ([see examples](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/xmltable-convert-xml-data-into-rows-and-columns-using-sql)):

```
SELECT t.foo, xt.*
FROM t, XMLTABLE('//TextblockParameter'
    PASSING t.xmlcol
    COLUMNS
        tagName VARCHAR2(100) PATH './tagName',
        value VARCHAR2(100) PATH './value'
) xt;
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1d8c6f02f6e425fa57eec9527e9f572d)

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
select extract(col1, '//value') from t;
```

> ```
> create table t (col1 xmltype);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into t values ('
> <MessageData>
>   <TextblockParameters>
>     <TextblockParameter>
>       <tagName>BUSINESSPROCESSID</tagName>
>       <value>RETAIL</value>
>     </TextblockParameter>
>     <TextblockParameter>
>       <tagName>SEGMENT</tagName>
>       <value>RESIDENTIAL</value>
>     </TextblockParameter>
>     <TextblockParameter>
>       <tagName>TRANSACTIONTYPE</tagName>
>       <value>PURCHASE</value>
>     </TextblockParameter>
>     <TextblockParameter>
>       <tagName>LANGUAGE</tagName>
>       <value>EST</value>
>     </TextblockParameter>
>   </TextblockParameters>
> </MessageData>');
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select extract(col1, '//value') from t;
> ```
>
> ```
> | EXTRACT(COL1,'//VALUE')                                                                                  |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | <value>RETAIL</value><br><value>RESIDENTIAL</value><br><value>PURCHASE</value><br><value>EST</value><br> |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5be7376db79afc0c315a0826d4d58e2f)*

Comment: Got error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Comment: what is your source column type?

Comment: try `select extract(XMLTYPE(col1), '//value') from t`

Comment: extract (and extractvalue) are deprecated functions, so I wouldn't recommend anyone use them. XMLTABLE is the way forward.